# Classification of Linear and Nonlinear ODEs

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations

I just want someone to verify if my answers are correct or not. Here is the question statement:

1. Determine which of the following ODEs are linear. For each of the linear ODEs indicate which are homogenous.

My answers are to the right of each ODE.

| no. | equation | classification |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | $xy''+x^2y'+(\sin x)y=x$ | (linear-inhomogeneous) |
| 2 | $xy''+x^2y'+(\sin x)y=y$ | (nonlinear) |
| 3 | $xy'+2e^xy=0$ | (linear-homogeneous) |
| 4 | $y''+y'+\sin y=0$ | (nonlinear) |
| 5 | $y''+y'+\sin x=0$ | (linear-inhomogeneous) |
| 6 | $y'''+y''+x^2y'+x^3y=0$ | (linear-homogeneous) |
| 7 | $y''+x^2y'+(\sin x)y=y^2$ | (nonlinear) |
| 8 | $yy'+y'+2y=x$ | (nonlinear) |

Comment: Seems correct to me.

Comment: Why the second ode is nonlinear?

Comment: Not correct. The second one is linear. Also in the future use `\sin`.

Comment: @Wang I see the second one is linear homogeneous if I rewrite the equation. Thanks.

Comment: @K.defaoite Okay, will do.